# How to remove Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Somehow I have Windows® Assessment and Deployment Kit installed on my Windows 7 box, but no way to remove it from Control Panel --> Programs and Features.

Microsoft suggests using adksetup.exe, but I can't find that either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can re-download the adksetup.exe file from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652), it's a small file. Then open a command prompt as administrator, navigate to the adksetup.exe file and run this command:

```
adksetup /uninstall
```

Hope this helps,